# Erro 404 em POST com NODE e REACT

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, axios

Estou construindo uma aplicação com nodejs no back-end e react no frond-end.

Fiz uma função de cadastro porém não consigo realizar o POST, retornando:

> xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:3333/users net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

**Código no frond-end:**

**services/api.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3333',
});

export default api;
```

**./Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './pages/home';
import Users from './pages/users';

export default function Routes() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                <Route path="/users" exact component={Users} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

**./pages/users/index.js**

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import api from '../../services/api';

    export default function Users() {

    const [ firstName, setFirstName ] = useState('');
    const [ lastName, setLastName ] = useState('');
    const [ email, setEmail ] = useState('');
    const [ password, setPassword ] = useState('');

    async function handleUsers(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = {
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email,
            password
        };

        try{
           const response = await api.post('users', data)
            alert('Cadastro realizado!');
        } catch (err){
            alert('Cadastro não realizado.')
        } 
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <form onSubmit={handleUsers}>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Primeiro Nome"
                    value={firstName}
                    onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Último Nome"
                    value={lastName}
                    onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="E-mail"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
                <input 
                    type="password" 
                    placeholder="Senha"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
                <button className="" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**BACK-END**

**./src/routes.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const UserController = require('./controller/UserController');

const routes = express.Router();

routes.post('/users', UserController.create);

module.exports = routes;
```

**./src/controller/UserController.js**

```
const connection = require('../database/connection');

module.exports = {
    async create(request, response) {
        const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = request.body;

        await connection('users').insert({
            idUser,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email,
            password
        })

        return response.json({
            idUser
        });
    }
}
```

**TABELA:**

```
  table.increments('idUser').primary();
  table.string('firstName').notNullable();
  table.string('lastName').notNullable();
  table.string('email').notNullable();
  table.string('password').notNullable();
```

**CONEXÃO**

```
const knex = require('knex');
const configuration = require('../../knexfile');

const connection = knex(configuration.development);

module.exports = connection;
```

**ERROS:**

**FRONTEND:**

> ./src/pages/users/index.js
>     Line 22:18:  'response' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

**BACKEND:**

> (node:32088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise 
>   which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)

NAVEGADOR:

> POST http://localhost:3333/users net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
>
> POST http://localhost:3333/users net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: O `idUser` não foi declarado no Controller...

Comment: Exatamente! O cadastro foi realizado, obrigado! Aproveitando, poderia me dizer o porque da mensagem " 'response' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars" no meu front-end?

Comment: Porque você recebeu o valor, colocou na variável `response` e não fez nada com ela (`is assigned a value but never used`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Front você não precisa setar a constante response.
Não é algo que vai impedir seu código de funcionar, mas é interessante você não deixar variáveis soltas assim.

Procure sobre como usar ESLint/Prettier depois, ele pode te ajudar nisso.

```
    async function handleUsers(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = {
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email,
            password
        };

        try{
            await api.post('users', data)
            alert('Cadastro realizado!');
        } catch (err){
            alert('Cadastro não realizado.')
        } 
    }
```